# Como abrir arquivo separando cada linha em um item de uma lista/tupla?

Tags: python, arquivo

No PHP, temos uma função chamada `file` que, ao abrir um arquivo, faz com que cada linha seja colocada em um item de um `array`.

Exemplo:

*hello.txt*

```
   olá
   mundo
```

*script php*

```
file('hello.txt'); // array('olá', 'mundo')
```

Em Python, como eu poderia fazer para ler cada linha de arquivo em um item de uma `list` ou `tuple`?

Existe uma maneira simples como é feita em PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Faz assim:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    list_lines = f.readlines() # ['  1 linha  \n', '  2 linha  \n' ...]
```

Para remover as quebras de linha e/ou espaços extra, tabs do final/início da linha fazes:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    list_lines = [i.strip() for i in f] # ['1 linha', '2 linha' ...]
```

Ou remover apenas as quebras de linha (`\n`):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    list_lines = f.read().splitlines() # ['  1 linha  ', '  2 linha  ' ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Há uma resposta que vi no [Stackoverflow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) que é simplesmente fantástica.

Veja:

```
 lines = tuple(open('hello.txt', 'r'))
```

Simples e em uma linha!